# Created Nested JSON Instead of Separate JSON

Tags: python, json

So I have a small script the output of which I want to store as a JSON Object. Here is the script:

```
import dns.resolver
import json

def get(domain):
    ids = [
        'CNAME',
        'A',
        'NS',
    ]

    for _iter in ids:
        try:
            inf = dns.resolver.query(domain, _iter)
            response_dict["Domain"] = domain

            for _resp in inf:
                print(_iter, ':', _resp.to_text())
                response_dict[_iter] = _resp.to_text()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    # dump information as a JSON file. 'a' to append file.
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(response_dict, outfile)

    print(response_dict)        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    response_dict = dict()
    get("apple.com")
    get("google.com")
```

Now the output of this generates  separate objects in JSON as viz.

```
{"Domain": "apple.com", "A": "17.178.96.59", "NS": "b.ns.apple.com."}
{"Domain": "google.com", "A": "172.217.21.238", "NS": "ns3.google.com."}
```

What I actually want is:

[image: JSON]

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending to the file with each call to `get()`, append the results to a list and dump at the end. Also don't define `response_dict` in `__main__`.

```
import dns.resolver
import json

def get(domain):
    ids = [
        'CNAME',
        'A',
        'NS',
    ]

    response_dict = {}
    for _iter in ids:
        try:
            inf = dns.resolver.query(domain, _iter)
            response_dict["Domain"] = domain

            for _resp in inf:
                print(_iter, ':', _resp.to_text())
                response_dict[_iter] = _resp.to_text()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    print(response_dict)
    return response_dict  # return a value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    response_list = []
    # append each output of get() to this list
    response_list.append(get("apple.com"))
    response_list.append(get("google.com"))

    # write the list to a file
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
        json.dump(response_list, outfile)
```